# What does the Publication List 'Status' say Active, when they are unsubscribed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

I have imported a csv of contacts to a new publication list, with a Status column of 'Unsubscribe'.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT Status
FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE ListID = 'MyPublicationListID'
```

I can see that they all have the status of 'unsubscribed'.

But when I look in the Publication List itself, their Status is marked as 'Active':

[image]

Is this the All Subscribers Status rather than the Publication List status?

Comment: What did the import notification email say?  And can you update your question to include  the columns headings from your CSV?  Also, if you're unsubscribed in All Subs, then you'll be unsubscribed from all publications.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is an embarrassingly old Known Issue: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002CFQzQAO&title=publication-lists-status-inaccurate-on-the-user-interface

Disregard what you see in the Publication List. It's a bug.
The Query shows you the truth.